# $R$ is commutative ring with unity, prove $I,J\trianglelefteq R \wedge I+J=R \Rightarrow IJ=I\cap J$

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ a commutative ring with unity, and let $I,J\trianglelefteq R$ ideals such that $I+J=R$. Prove that $IJ=I\cap J$.
Recall $IJ=\{\sum_{k=1}^n i_kj_k:i_k\in I,j_k\in J, k\in \mathbb{N} \}$.

---

I have shown that $IJ\subseteq I\cap J$. The rest of the solution does not use the commutativity of $R$ so my question is where is the mistake:

Let $a\in I\cap J$. $a=a\cdot 1\in IJ$ thus $I\cap J=IJ$.

Comment: You have assumed $1\in J\implies J=R$.

Comment: @YadatiKiran Why? One of the properties of an ideal $I$ is $\forall a\in I \forall r\in R, ar,ra\in I$.

Comment: @J.Doe: Precisely $a=a\cdot1\in I$ not $IJ$ because $1\in R$.

Comment: Interesting, a user named "Jon D" posted [a very similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3034653/29335) question yesterday. If you are the same person, please stop.  One of the suggested duplicates contains an example for noncommutative rings.

Comment: I meant, "please stop posting as more than one account," that is.

Comment: @rschwieb No, that wasn't me (the profile picture is different). When I looked my question up I didn't find it is duplicated, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Yadati Kiran mentioned in their comment, $1$ is not in general an element of $J$. While it is true that $a\cdot 1\in I$ by one of the properties of an ideal (as you mention in your recent comment), how do you deduce that $a\cdot 1\in IJ$? If $1$ were an element of $J$ this would follow, but as Yadati Kiran pointed out, this is not the case in general.

Here is a hint on how to proceed instead: Your intuition to be skeptical of a solution that doesn't use all of the assumptions was right - but you also did not use I+J=R yet. This allows you to write $1=i+j$ with $i\in I,j\in J$. Now if $a\in I\cap J$, try to rewrite $a=a\cdot 1=a\cdot (i+j)=(a\cdot i)+(a\cdot j)$ in a way that shows this is an element of $IJ$ - you will want to use commutativity here.